# R association rules apriori -- suppress grouping of items

Tags: r, dataframe, arules

I'm using the `apriori` function from the `arules` package to perform analyses for item association. After coercing the results into a datframe, I notice the output can be grouped like so in some instances:

```
 LHS                 RHS        Support        Confidence      Lift        Count
{Item1, Item2}      {Item3}      .84             0.99          12.3          6
```

Is there a way for force the function to perform the analysis just between two items in each transaction and yield the corresponding support, confidence, etc? In other words, can I force `apriori` to split the above result into something like:

```
 LHS           RHS        Support        Confidence      Lift       Count
{Item1}      {Item3}        a                b            c           d
{Item2}      {Item3}        e                f            g           h
```

Comment: The two results that you show are not equivalent. The first one (with {Item1, Item2}) means that if _both_ Item1 and Item2 are present, Item3 is likely to be present, The second (two line) version would mean that if either Item 1 or Item 2 is present, Item3 is likely. Are you trying to transform the rules that you got, or do you want to force apriori to give only rules with a single item on the LHS?

Comment: @G5W I know that I could pass the `maxlen` parameter in `apriori`, but, if I'm not mistaken, that functions more as a filter once the analysis is complete. I guess what I'm asking is more along the rule transformation side in that can `apriori` determine a rule for just 2 items even if it can determine a rule for those 2 same items along with others, potentially?

Answer (score 0):

`maxlen` in apriori does not act as a filter after mining. apriori creates frequent itemsets starting with length 1 then 2, 3, ... and `maxlen` stops the mining process.

`minlen` on the other hand is a filter because all shorter frequent itemsets have to be found first.

If you are asking if you can determine support and confidence of

```
{Item1} -> {Item3}
{Item2} -> {Item3}
```

by just using the support and confidence of

```
{Item1, Item2} -> {Item3}
```

then the answer is no. However, from the apriori property we know at least the following:

```
supp({Item1} -> {Item3}) >= supp({Item1, Item2} -> {Item3})
supp({Item2} -> {Item3}) >= supp({Item1, Item2} -> {Item3})
```